# Differentiation answer check

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\arcsin \sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}} + \arctan \sqrt{x} \mbox{.}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{x+1}}} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x}} \cdot -x^{-2} + \frac{1}{1+x} \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = -\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{x^2}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x} + 2x}\mbox{.}$$
Is there anything else I can do with the answer?

Comment: maybe simplify the radical terms by multiply through with their LCD

Comment: Is there a way to simplify it further?

Comment: Write the 1 inside the radical as x+1 over x+1 and combine

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
Let $\displaystyle\arcsin\sqrt{\frac x{x+1}}=y$

$$\implies \sqrt{\frac x{x+1}}=\sin y\implies \frac x{x+1}=\sin^2y$$

$$\implies x=\tan^2y\implies \sqrt x=\tan y \implies y=\arctan \sqrt x$$

---

Alternatively, let $\displaystyle\arctan \sqrt x=u\implies \sqrt x=\tan u\implies x=\tan^2u$

$\displaystyle\implies \frac x{x+1}=\frac{\tan^2u}{1+\tan^2u}=\frac{\tan^2u}{\sec^2u}=\sin^2u$

$\displaystyle\implies \arcsin\sqrt{\frac x{x+1}}=\arcsin (\sin u)=u=\arctan \sqrt x$

Comment: That seems pretty clever but I don't understand the full implication of it. Could you elaborate.

Comment: @vilbur, so $f(x)=2\arctan\sqrt x$

Comment: You essentially rewrote the arcsine term. Not bad. (+1) But no introductory calc student would do that by his own account...

Comment: @imranfat, any better & intuitive way is more than welcome

Comment: I like your method, but what I mean is, that these problems occur in calc 1 or 2 as an identity problem and the purpose is that students take the derivative and show that they are equal. Meaning that their anti derivatives only differ by a constant. I got a bunch of those problems for my calc students, no one dares to rewrite them as the way you did. Very clever, but it takes some extra knowledge (or experience if you wish) to come up with that. I am keeping your answer with me for the next semester...

Comment: @imranfat, I think, one who is acquainted with Trigonometry, should be asked to check $\frac x{x+1}$ when $x=\tan^2\theta$ or $\cot^2\theta;$ $\frac x{1-x}$ when $x=\sin^2\theta$ or $\cos^2\theta;$ and $\frac x{x-1}$ when $x=\sec^2\theta,\csc^2\theta$ as preparation of calculus

Comment: I agree with you, however lots of students entering our calc sequence (unfortunately) don't have the best trig skills. That scenario would be unthinkeable in the sub continent, but here in North America, this is an all too common issue. I deal with it semester after semester. What I mean is that in your specific method, I must add a "leading up" question to make them do those steps before they do the actual problem. My intention is to give it a try in Spring

Comment: @imranfat, thanks. it's really nice to share ideas. My teacher always used to say: If you know Trigonometry, Calculus(basic) is only matter of time. Btw, how about starting $$\arcsin\sqrt{\frac x{x+1}}=y?$$

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would submit. Nothing doing, sonny!

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I was stating that the answer the OP got was the same as mine and that there isn't much simplification that can be done. No need to down vote. . .

Comment: Yours came on my screen earlier than Lab's, downvote undone